# I need to create a class what have a propeties. And one of them, must be a property with property, idk how to explaine it

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, class, types

something like this

```
export class QueryParam {
    [name: string]: string;
}
```

or

```
export class QueryParam {
     value: string;
    [name: string]: value;
}
```

and then I wnat to use it in my other class somethink like

```
this.sideNav = [
        {
            link: `/${routeConstants.list}`,
            text: "Decks",
            queryParams: [{ name: "resource", value: resourceNames.Deck }],
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a group of query params so you can use the same type that the router uses: `Params`. It looks like this:

```
export declare type Params = {
    [key: string]: any;
};
```

so your sideNav would become:

```
this.sideNav = [
  {
    link: `/${routeConstants.list}`,
    text: "Decks",
    queryParams: {
      resource: resourceNames.Deck
    },
 },
```

and multiple params would just be:

```
queryParams: {
  one: 'one',
  two: 'two',
  ...etc
}
```